# Sublime text not flushing automatically, c code

Tags: c, sublimetext3, flush

I'm trying to execute my compiled c file from ST using this build system:

```
{
   "working_dir" : "$file_path",


   "selector": "source.x",

   "shell_cmd": "${file_path}/${file_base_name}.x",
   "file_regex":  "^([^:]*):([0-9]+):[0-9]+: (?:error|note):"



}
```

however:

```
printf("hello world \n");
```

does not print during execution, but only when i quit the program (that's a big problem for me).

however:

```
 printf("hello world \n");
fflush(stdout);
```

Print immediately during exection.

Any idea ?

Comment: you already got the idea, didn't you? printf doesn't guarantee any flushing

Comment: no, the /n should force the auto flushing!

Comment: this is not required by spec